# Changing Values in a Data Series

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I want to change the values in one column of my dataframe so that my data is actually altered. This is what I've done:

```
cgc_data['return_sign'].apply(lambda val : 1.0 if val >= 0 else 0)
```

But this is what I get:

```
cgc_data.groupby(['return_sign']).mean()

Price   1d ret  5d ret  10d ret 15d ret 3d sma  10d sma 10d ema
return_sign                             
-1.0    14.514507   -0.028492   -0.020618   -0.014593   -0.006056   14.819721   14.920520   14.882363
0.0 4.026313    0.000000    0.002574    0.007628    -0.004837   4.023833    3.922193    3.959923
1.0 14.979745   0.035238    0.044716    0.062569    0.079726    14.632116   14.462354   14.509330
```

I still have 0s.  How do I make adjustments to the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reassign the value back to the original dataframe.

```
cgc_data['return_sign'] = np.where(cgc_data['return_sign'] >= 0, 1, 0)
```

Also the `.apply` can be improved by leveraging vectorization using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cgc_data.loc[:,'return_sign'] = cgc_data.return_sign.apply(lambda val : 1.0 if val >= 0 else 0)
```

You need to re-write the result into `return_sign` column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you returned the data after using the `.apply` function.
Try this:

```
cgc_data['return_sign'] = cgc_data['return_sign'].apply(lambda val : 1.0 if val >= 0 else 0)
```

And then proceed with your next step

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on a single column never use `apply` as it is very slow. Instead use `map`

```
cgc_data['return_sign'] = cgc_data['return_sign'].map(lambda val : 1.0 if val >= 0 else 0)
```

Hope this helps!!